# How to access hard drive after after ubuntu14.04 install

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a Hp desktop pc that I recently purchased for my wife. It only has one connection for a hard drive. I removed the Windows 8 hard drive and replaced it with another hard drive to install Ubuntu on. The install goes good until the restart at the end of the install then after it reboots, I get a message that says No boot device. I tried all the combinations of settings in the bios that I could think of with no succsess after many reinstalls. I even tried using A usb3 Dock with the hard drive in it. I feel it has something to do with the uefi but not sure. I don't want to duel boot.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: did you turn off secureboot?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely secure boot prevents you from booting. open the bios and look for secure boot, then disable it.

http://www.howtogeek.com/175641/how-to-boot-and-install-linux-on-a-uefi-pc-with-secure-boot/